# Create Post with Meta Field – WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have just started with REST API and using it for creating posts from frontend. I managed to publish post with Title, Excerpt, Content.
I want to add a Custom Meta Field value aswell, any example or help is much appreciated.

This is my Ajax Code, all other fields working fine except meta value is not being added in post

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
$( '#post-submission-form' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $( '#post-submission-title' ).val();
    var excerpt = $( '#post-submission-excerpt' ).val();
    var content = $( '#post-submission-content' ).val();
    var status = 'draft';

    var data = {
        title: title,
        excerpt: excerpt,
        content: content,
        status: status,
        meta: {
            'video_url_url' : 'abc',
        }

    };

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wp/v2/posts',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
            alert( POST_SUBMITTER.success );
        },
        fail : function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
            alert( POST_SUBMITTER.failure );
        }

    });

});
```

} );

Comment: Solved it. I had to register meta field first in order to read or write.

`$object_type = 'post';
$args1 = array( // Validate and sanitize the meta value.
    // 'number' must be used as 'type'.
    'type'         => 'string',
    // Shown in the schema for the meta key.
    'description'  => 'A meta key associated with a string meta value.',
    // Return a single value of the type.
    'single'       => true,
    // Show in the WP REST API response.
    'show_in_rest' => true,
);
register_meta( $object_type, 'video_url_url', $args1 );`

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. I still can't get it to work. Can you please take a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43265580/100747

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php :

```
/**
 * Add the meta fields to REST API responses for posts read and write
 * Read and write a post meta fields in post responses
 */
function mg_register_meta_api() {
    //Meta Fields that should be added to the API 
    $meta_fields = array(
        'video_url_url',
        'another_meta_key'
    );
    //Iterate through all fields and add register each of them to the API
    foreach ($meta_fields as $field) {
        register_rest_field( 'ring',
            $field,
            array(
                'get_callback'    => array( $this, 'mg_fw_get_meta'),
                'update_callback' => array( $this, 'mg_fw_update_meta'),
                'schema'          => null,
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'mg_register_meta_api' );

/**
 * Handler for getting custom field data.
 *
 * @since 0.1.0
 * 
 * @param array $object The object from the response
 * @param string $field_name Name of field
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function mg_get_meta( $object, $field_name ) {
    return get_post_meta( $object[ 'id' ], $field_name );
}

/**
 * Handler for updating custom field data.
 *
 * @since 0.1.0
 * @link  http://manual.unyson.io/en/latest/helpers/php.html#database
 * @param mixed $value The value of the field
 * @param object $object The object from the response
 * @param string $field_name Name of field
 *
 * @return bool|int
 */
function mg_update_meta( $value, $object, $field_name ) {
    if ( ! $value || ! is_string( $value ) ) {
        return;
    }

    return update_post_meta( $object->ID, $field_name, maybe_serialize( strip_tags( $value ) ) );
}
```

Now you should be able to read and write for meta 'video_url_url' using the api.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with this today and came up with the following solution that works well and adds multiple fields.

Hope this helps anyone who may be stuck on this.

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'foo_register_meta_api' );

    function foo_register_meta_api() {
        // Meta Fields to add to the API
        $meta_fields = array(
            'field_1',
            'foo_bar',
            'foobar',
            'another_field'
        );
        // Loop all fields and register each of them to the API
        foreach ($meta_fields as $field) {
            register_rest_field( 'my-post-type',
                $field,
                array(
                    'get_callback'    => function ($params) use ($field) {
                        return \get_post_meta($params['id'], $field);
                    },
                    'update_callback' => function ($value, $object, $fieldName){
                        return \update_post_meta($object->ID, $fieldName, $value);
                    },
                    'schema' => null
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to save `phy_marks` in post type `candidates`. What I've got is creating the post but not saving `phy_marks`.

My JSON data:

```
{ "title": "Why not working finally","content": "Test", "status": "publish" ,"post_type": "candidates", "meta": {
  "phy_marks": 66 } }
```

My Code:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'foo_register_meta_api' );

function foo_register_meta_api() {
    // Meta Fields to add to the API
    $meta_fields = array(
        'phy_marks'
    );
    // Loop all fields and register each of them to the API
    foreach ($meta_fields as $field) {
        register_rest_field( 'candidates',
            $field,
            array(
                'get_callback'    => function ($params) use ($field) {
                    return \get_post_meta($params['id'], $field);
                },
                'update_callback' => function ($value, $object, $fieldName){
                    return \update_post_meta($object->ID, $fieldName, $value);
                },
                'schema' => null
            )
        );
    }
}
```